# Android : How to show horinzontal Scrollbars ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment, horizontal-scrolling

I have been trying to enable horizontal scroll bars but to no vain. This method

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       getListView().setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
}
```

but its just not working. Any tips will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting it in the xml?

Comment: I'm am using a `ListFragment ` so I am not inflating a custom view. The `onCreateView()` method return `super.onCreate...` and i retrieve the created `ListView` as above. @Andy Joyce Thanks for the suggestion by the way

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the scroll view in xml file 
Here is the example 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/